# CUDA : Copy non-zero values position of a vector to another

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

On GPGPU, with cuda my problem is:
I have a vector of 256 elements, I want to make a program that can extract the positions of non-zero values ​​and copy them to another vector.

My code not work:

**dev_Hist :** is source of data, initial vector ;

**dev_Xn :** is vector of non-zeros values position on dev_Hist ;

**nN :** is number of non zeros values on dev_Hist

**1. Kernel call :**

```
gpu_Xn<<<1, nN>>>(dev_Hist, nN, dev_Xn) ;
```

**2. Device function**

```
__global__ void gpu_Xn(int *pHist, int pnN, int* pXn) 
{
    int Tid ;
    Tid = threadIdx.x ;

    __shared__ T tmpXn[256] ;

    tmpXn[Tid] = 0 ;

    __syncthreads() ;

    __shared__ int idx ;

    if(Tid == 0)
        idx = -1  ;

    syncthreads() ;

    if(pHist[Tid] !=0)
    {
        atomicAdd(&idx, 1) ; 
        tmpXn[idx] = Tid ;
    }

    __syncthreads() ;
    if(Tid < pnN)
        pXn[Tid] = tmpXn[Tid] ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are not using `atomicAdd` correctly. Although you are atomically incrementing the value of `idx`, the *read* of `idx` for the store to shared memory isn't atomic, which  will produce undefined behaviour.

Your kernel probably should look like this:

```
__global__ void gpu_Xn(int *pHist, int pnN, int* pXn) 
{
    int Tid ;
    Tid = threadIdx.x ;

    __shared__ int tmpXn[256] ;
    __shared__ int idx ;

    tmpXn[Tid] = -1 ;
    if(Tid == 0) idx = 0  ;

    __syncthreads() ;

    if(pHist[Tid] !=0)
    {
        int x = atomicAdd(&idx, 1) ; 
        tmpXn[x] = Tid ;
    }

    __syncthreads() ;
    if(Tid < pnN)
        pXn[Tid] = tmpXn[Tid] ;
}
```

[disclaimer: written in browser, never compiled, use at own risk]

Note that `atomicAdd` returns the previous value of the location being atomically updated. It is that value you need to use when loading to shared memory.